# Is there any way to avoid Scala libraries appearing twice in an Eclipse/Scala/Maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, scala, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have

- Eclipse 3.5.2
- Scala 2.8.0 final (inc latest Scala IDE for Eclipse)
- Maven integration for Eclipse
- Maven 2.2.1
- .project and .classpath files generated by `maven-eclipse-plugin`

I'm using Scala to write Specs BDD tests for my Java code and the setup above is working very nicely so far. However, I have one puzzling problem and I would like to know whether anyone knows how to resolve it.

The Scala libraries are appearing in my project twice.

1. in the M2 ClassPath (as a Maven Dependency)
2. as an Eclipse System Library (in the same manner as the JRE System Libraries)

Consequently, when I `Ctrl-Shft-T` every Scala class appears twice.

Can this be avoided without breaking my Scala project in either the command line or the Workspace?

Comment: As a side note, I don't think you should use `eclipse:eclipse` when using m2eclipse.

Comment: Exactly. not since the `eclipse:m2eclipse` goal is gone has the `maven-eclipse-plugin` been of much use to m2eclipse users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question,

it appears (as hinted at by all above) that `maven-eclipse-plugin` is essentially obsolete. When I

- deleted my old eclipse project
- removed all eclipse files (ie `.settings` and `.project` from my project directory)
- removed all references to `maven-eclipse-plugin` from my `pom`
- installed the `m2eclipse-scala` plugin
- re-imported the project as a maven project

all settings were detected correctly and I no longer saw the double entry of scala classes in my classpath.

Comment: The most accurate information and the latest developments on using the Scala IDE for Eclipse with m2eclipse can be found at http://scala-ide.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/With_M2Eclipse ... which is where you'd have been pointed if you'd followed my advice earlier ;-)

Comment: Thanks Miles, I did follow your advice and it was very useful. However because I still had the maven-eclipse-plugin generated metadata messing up my project configuration I first had to remove that.

Answer (score 3):

The best place for questions like this is the [Scala IDE user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user).

The most up to date documentation on using the Scala tooling for Eclipse with Maven via m2eclipse can be found [here](http://scala-ide.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/With_M2Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks Miles, you're very helpful as ever. Unfortunately nearly all websites are better indexed than any guidance you might have previously given in the mailing list. I was sent in the wrong direction by the following two links, 

http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites-snapshots/maven-scala-plugin/faq.html

http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/wiki/ScalaEclipseMaven